# Pausing a dynamic display

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, animation

I'm trying to display some graphs, which were defined with plot above this line of code. The parametric plot moves through all of the x values, the others are stationary. I would like the parametric plot to pause at a specific value (x = 14.9475). Any ideas? Perhaps nesting the following code inside of a `Dynamic` or `Manipulate`.

```
Animate[
  Show[
    Hill, Antsight, BladeofGrass, 
    ParametricPlot[{x + a, Hillheight[x] + a Derivative[1][Hillheight][x]}, {a, 0, 32}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 10}}], {x, 0, 32}]
```

So far I've been playing around with this.

```
Do[{Animate[
   Show[{Hill, Antsight, BladeofGrass, 
     ParametricPlot[{x + a, 
       Hillheight[x] + a Derivative[1][Hillheight][x]}, {a, 0, 32}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 10}}], {x, 0, 32}]}, 
 If[x == 14.9475, Break[]];
 Pause[0.2], {x, 0, 32, 0.1}]
```

Heres the rest of the code.

```
Hillheight[x_] := (1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2
Hill = Plot[(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2, {x, 0, 32},Filling -> Bottom, PlotStyle -> Brown]

BladeofGrass = ParametricPlot[{32, 1/5 + y}, {y, 0, 39/5}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]
Antsight = ListLinePlot[{{32, 8}, {14.9475, Hillheight[14.9475]}}, {PlotStyle ->
         Dashed}]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to help you out without having definitions for your various graphs.  If I understand your question, you want to pause an Animator at a particular spot.  Here's a proof of concept example:

```
DynamicModule[{i, t},
 Column@{Animator[Dynamic[i], {0, 10}, 
    AnimationTimeIndex -> Dynamic[t]], 
   Dynamic@Plot[Sin[x + i], {x, 0, 10}],
   Dynamic@If[1.90 < t < 2.00, (Pause[1]; t = 2;), ""]
   }]
```

[image]

I create my own `Animate` so I can capture the value of `AnimationTimeIndex` (which was introduced in v10, so this won't work in earlier versions).  The `DefaultDuration` is set to 5 seconds so I stop the animation at 40% through, pause for a second, and restart close to that point.

You'll note that there are some kinks to work out.  For reasons not known to me, setting my dynamic `t` to 2 after the pause does not seem to set `AnimationTimeIndex` properly.  Also, not shown in the animated gif is an ugly nested `If` statement that shows up upon Initialization (and goes away pretty quickly).  Lastly, note that there are 3 rows in the column; the `If` statement *must print something in order for this to work*.  I have it printing "".

Comment: Hopefully the added code helped some, is there any way to set it to pause at an x-coordinate though? even if you could enter any value

Comment: I will try to update with your code when I get a chance.  To answer the 2nd part of your question, I *think* the answer is yes, since teh `DefaultDuration` is 5 s, so a particular x value would appear at (xmax-xmin)/5 where xmax and xmin are the end/start values in the `Animate`.